# Writing CSV files - fill columns with whitespace or not?

Tags: csv, whitespace

When doing various data analysis, it often makes sense to save some intermediate results as a CSV file. Could be for documentation, or to hand over to colleagues that want to work with Excel or similar or to have a quick way to do a sanity check yourself.

But how do I best format such a CSV file? Let's assume I want to have a classic spreadsheet with a header row and the data in columns. Like so:

```
Device_id;Location;Mean_reading;Error_count
opti-1;Upper-Underburg Backroad 2;1.45;42
ac-4;Valley 23;0.1;2
level-245;Lower-Underburg Central Market Place;1034;5
```

For opening it in Excel or reading it in with pandas, this works flawlessly, as long as you specify the use of `;` as separator. However, as you can see with this example, it's quite hard to read when opening it up in a simple text editor, the use of which might be preferable in many cases (remote access, faster opening, no assumptions needed about separator or decimal dot vs. comma etc).

So I could simply add some whitespace to make the CSV look like this:

```
Device_id   ;Location                                ;Mean_reading ;Error_count
opti-1      ;Upper-Underburg Backroad 2              ;1.45         ;42
ac-4        ;Valley 23                               ;0.1          ;2
level-245   ;Lower-Underburg Central Market Place    ;1034         ;5
```

But should I?
**Are there any documented best practices or standards on how to write CSV files in such cases?**
I can see pros and cons for both ways (see below), so I'm wondering if there's any guidelines on which way to go.

*I'm leaning towards the latter way and looking at what kind of CSV files I do get out of various data loggers or other software, this seems to be the prefered way, but on the other hand, searching for `CSV whitespace` on this here site mostly results in questions about how to get rid of it.*

*And I can see some potential issues with the needed length of the fields, since I either need to make assumptions (i.e. `Location` needs a length of 40 characters) that might or might not be correct (What happens when I place a device in `Underburg western motorway industrial estate northern fence`?) or I need some potentially expensive logic to figure out the needed field lengths.*

Comment: This is asking for opinions and personal preferences.

Comment: I'm specifically asking for documented best practices, i.e. NOT opinions! I already have an opinion, but I'm wondering whether I'm on the right path or not.

Answer (score 2):

I work daily with CSV data files (in the printing industry, where CSV still is the common denominator). I usually tell customers that the format to choose depends on the purpose.

CSV files without whitespace is for machine (software) reading, OR where you can have a common separator that is not used elsewhere - if you want to avoid the path of escaping the separators.

Fixed-width-files are better for humans, or where the separator chosen will at times be part of the text. It comes at a penalty if you use spaces to separate since fixed-width will take up more space. And, as you point out, you need to know the longest possible field in advance. This type of file format for my customers are mostly result export from legacy software dating back many years.

A variant to consider could be TAB separated files, since you can choose on the viewer / editor part how wide a TAB should be. That way, you are less depending on the field size.

Or, keep it as compact version for machine reading, and make yourself a temporary copy using AWK as a filter. It's trivial to do, and you can have the field length anything you want, without modifying the original file.